# Is it good practice to use the latest versions of dependencies when publishing?

Tags: rust, dependency-management, rust-cargo

I'm building a crate that uses a few dependencies and in order to publish it, I had to specify the dependencies' versions. I replaced my `dep = "*"` by `dep = ">=N"` with `N` being for each dep the latest version that I could get after a `cargo update`.

Should I relax/lower the versions required?

How could I do that? I've tried to set `dep = "M"` with `M` being a much lower version number but `cargo` keeps using the newer one. Is there a tool to find the minimum `M` required to build and test my crate?

Comment: In general you should use caret requirements (like `bitflags = "^1.2.1") as it makes sure cargo only uses compatible versions of the dependency (in this case, version 1.2.5 and 1.5.2 would be allowed, but not 1.1.7, 1.2.0, or 2.1.3) see [the cargo book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

Under [The `version` field](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-version-field), The Cargo Book states:

> Cargo bakes in the concept of [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/), so make sure you follow some basic rules:
>
> - Before you reach 1.0.0, anything goes, but if you make breaking changes, increment the minor version. In Rust, breaking changes include adding fields to structs or variants to enums.
> - After 1.0.0, only make breaking changes when you increment the major version. Don’t break the build.
> - After 1.0.0, don’t add any new public API (no new `pub` anything) in patch-level versions. Always increment the minor version if you add any new `pub` structs, traits, fields, types, functions, methods or anything else.
> - Use version numbers with three numeric parts such as 1.0.0 rather than 1.0.

If the maintainers of your dependencies have adopted and correctly applied these rules then, given a specific version of that dependency (which you know your crate to work against), any subsequent patch release of the same major version *should* always work—and subsequent minor releases of the same major version *should* also always work so long as the major version is not 0.

As [Herman L alludes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61700920/cargo-lowest-versions-of-dependencies#comment109144080_61700920), you can specify that you want the latest such "compatible" release by using the caret prefix.  He directed you to the Cargo book's chapter on [Specifying Dependencies](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html), which explains:

> #### Caret requirements
>
> **Caret requirements** allow SemVer compatible updates to a specified version. An update is allowed if the new version number does not modify the left-most non-zero digit in the major, minor, patch grouping. In this case, if we ran `cargo update -p time`, cargo should update us to version `0.1.13` if it is the latest `0.1.z` release, but would not update us to `0.2.0`. If instead we had specified the version string as `^1.0`, cargo should update to `1.1` if it is the latest `1.y` release, but not `2.0`. The version `0.0.x` is not considered compatible with any other version.
>
> Here are some more examples of caret requirements and the versions that would be allowed with them:
>
> ```
> ^1.2.3  :=  >=1.2.3, <2.0.0
> ^1.2    :=  >=1.2.0, <2.0.0
> ^1      :=  >=1.0.0, <2.0.0
> ^0.2.3  :=  >=0.2.3, <0.3.0
> ^0.2    :=  >=0.2.0, <0.3.0
> ^0.0.3  :=  >=0.0.3, <0.0.4
> ^0.0    :=  >=0.0.0, <0.1.0
> ^0      :=  >=0.0.0, <1.0.0
> ```
>
> This compatibility convention is different from SemVer in the way it treats versions before 1.0.0. While SemVer says there is no compatibility before 1.0.0, Cargo considers `0.x.y` to be compatible with `0.x.z`, where `y ≥ z` and `x > 0`.

However, it is of course possible that some package maintainers may ignore SemVer and instead adopt some other versioning scheme; may attempt using SemVer but apply it incorrectly; or may inadvertently make breaking changes without realising it.  Fortunately, the most popular crates are pretty active and well-maintained and issues like these are (in my experience) relatively rare.  Rust's strong type system also provides some added protection by preventing many such breaking changes from even compiling, so they're often caught very early.

Of course, all breaking changes should be picked up by your integration tests (which your build pipeline always ensures pass before you publish, right?).  The likes of Dependabot can also alert you to dependencies that are updated after you release (e.g. by creating a PR), which in turn can trigger your CI pipeline to immediately run your test suite against the new dependency version and report the results.

There may be good reason to adopt a different approach, but the above will broadly be sensible in most situations.